# How to write a function that will return part of char * in C?

Tags: c, arrays, substring

I want to return part (or let's say substring) of a char* in C. The point is that user defines the starting index and the length that I want to return. First of all, I check whether the given values are in the range and positive, if they are not, I want to return a null.

Here is what I have tried:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char * f(char a[], int start, int len, int lenA)
{
    int i, j = 1;
    char *temp;

    if ((start + len) > lenA)
        return NULL;
    if (start < 0 || len < 0)
        return NULL;
    else if (len == 0) {
        temp = malloc(sizeof(char)*1);
        return temp;
    }

    temp = malloc(sizeof(char)*len);
    for (i = 0; len >= j; i++, j++) {
        temp[i] = a[start];
        start++;
    }

    return temp;
}

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    char *a = {'a', 'b', 'c'};

    a = f(a, 0, 2, 3);

    int size = sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);

    if (a != NULL) {
        printf("{");
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            printf("'%c',", a[i]);
            if (i < (size - 1))
                printf(" ");
        }
        printf("}\n");
    }
    else printf("null\n");

    return 0;

}
```

The point is that when I when I run it, I get an error message saying: `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`
Instead, it should print this: `{'a', 'b'}`. While as you can see in my main, I called the function with 0 start index, and length of two, so it should get the first two characters. Any idea, how to fix it?

Comment: In which line do you get the error? Also, `sizeof(a)` returns the size of a pointer, not the size of the construct that `a` points to. And you don't free the malloc'ed memory.

Comment: @MrLister it doesn't show any line number, it compiles, but when I run it I get a segmentation fault error.

Comment: In that case, add some diagnostics output to the program in strategic places. Things like `puts("Now about to calculate the size");` so that you know how far the program gets before it crashes.

Comment: You have to run your program in a debugger.

Comment: Anyway, the bad definition of `size` causes problems; it should be 2 in the example, but it becomes 4 (or 8, depending on your setup). So you are reading beyond the allocated memory.

Comment: @MrLister Thanks for the info. One more thing, do I need the both malloc statements? If yes, where can I free them without breaking the program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   char *a = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
```

is not valid C code. Please enable your compiler warnings.

If you want an array of `char` use:

```
char a[]  = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
```

or for a null terminated string:

```
char a[] =  "abc";
```

Comment: If I change it like that, it even doesn't compile, I get an error message: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char[3]’ from type ‘char *’

Comment: Use another pointer variable for your return value: `char *b; b = f(a, 0, 2, 3);`

Comment: How are you compiling?

Comment: Yes, that worked. A quick question. Is there any way to decide the length of my new array, in this case b? While in my example it should just print {'a', 'b'}, but it prints {'a', 'b', ''}

Comment: The length of the resulting array is (or should be) the same as the third parameter, `len`, in the function. Or, you could use real C strings so that you can calculate the actual string length (at the cost of an extra allocated byte per string).

Comment: @MrLister I know, but as you can see my len parameter is 2, but my output is of len 3.

Comment: Like I said, that is because you calculate `size` wrongly. That was my very first comment.

Comment: @MrLister Then why don't you give me a code segment, how can I calculate it?

Comment: Either set size to whatever the len parameter is; for instance, you can `#define LEN 2` and then `b = f(a, 0, LEN, 3); size = LEN;` or you can use real, null-terminated, strings.

Comment: Really, if you use strings, you can write `temp = malloc(sizeof(char)*(len+1)); return strncpy(temp, a+start, len);` instead of everything starting from the first `else`.

Comment: @MrLister What about the free, where should I free the mallocs?

Comment: In the function, only one malloc is actually used, so you need only one free. At the end, after you're done using the result (i.e. after the `printf("}\n");` in main). I mean to write `calloc` though, to write the ending `\0'.

Comment: @MrLister But temp is inside the function, so if I do something like free(temp) will it work?

Comment: @ett That is a totally different question, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me on VS Express 2013. I didn't go through all your code. But I seem to have fixed the problem. **int size = sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);** - this shouldn't work. You're dividing the size of a pointer (4 bytes) by the size of a character (1 byte).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char * f(char a[], int start, int len, int lenA)
{
    int i, j = 1;
    char *temp;

    if ((start + len) > lenA)
        return NULL;
    if (start < 0 || len < 0)
        return NULL;
    else if (len == 0) {
        temp = malloc(sizeof(char)* 1);
        return temp;
    }

    temp = malloc(sizeof(char)*len);

    for (i = 0; len >= j; i++, j++) {
        temp[i] = a[start];
        start++;
    }

    return temp;
}

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    char arr[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c' }; //code changed here

    char *a = f(arr, 0, 2, 3); //code changed here

    int size = 2; //code changed here - consider using the same variable for the length above and size here

    if (a != NULL) {
        printf("{");
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            printf("%c,", a[i]);
            if (i < (size - 1))
                printf(" ");
        }
        printf("}\n");
    }
    else printf("null\n");

    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;

}
```

Let me know if you need any more help. I didn't test this for all cases. Also, don't forget to free the memory you are allocating dynamically.